# Stop displaying report in fit a model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kaggle

I am building a pipeline with XGGRegressor.
In step fit the model, kaggle displays:

```
[0] validation_0-rmse:195852.50000
[1] validation_0-rmse:194177.78125
[2] validation_0-rmse:192879.96875
[3] validation_0-rmse:191438.50000
[4] validation_0-rmse:189879.57812
[5] validation_0-rmse:188803.59375
[6] validation_0-rmse:187077.00000
[7] validation_0-rmse:185477.14062
[8] validation_0-rmse:184178.45312
[9] validation_0-rmse:182755.70312
[10]    validation_0-rmse:181168.15625
[11]    validation_0-rmse:180261.75000
[12]    validation_0-rmse:178957.35938
[13]    validation_0-rmse:177349.95312
[14]    validation_0-rmse:176673.50000
...
```

It is so long and sometime lost my time. How can I hide it in run code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `verbosity` of `xgboost` to 0 for silent, 1 for warning, 2 for info and 3 for debug as follows:

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgb.set_config(verbosity=1)
```